# Determine the mapping matrix $A=M_B^B$ with the base $B=(1,t,t^2,t^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, problem-solving, change-of-basis

Hey I have some problems with this problem

Consider all polynomials with $\leq \deg 3$ and the following map:

$f: \mathbb{R}[t] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[t]$

$f(t) \rightarrow f(t+1)-f(t)$

a) Determine the mapping matrix $A=M_B^B$ with the base $B=(1,t,t^2,t^3)$

b) Find a matrix $S \in Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $A \cdot S=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 0& 1 &0  &0 \\ 0&  0&  1&0 \\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So for a) I found the mapping of the polynomials in the Basis $B$.

So I have $1 \rightarrow 0$

$t \rightarrow 1$

$t^2 \rightarrow 2t+1$

$t^3 \rightarrow 3t^2+3t+1$

So I have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 &1  &1 \\ 0& 0 &2  &3 \\ 0&  0&  0&3 \\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ .

So far everything right?

For b) I thought to do $S=A^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 0& 1 &0  &0 \\ 0&  0&  1&0 \\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ but the problem is that $A$ is not invertible. So what I have done is solving this system

$\begin{vmatrix} 0&  1&  1&1 \\ 0&  0&  2& 3\\ 0&  0&  0& 3\\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix} 1&  0&  0&0 \\ 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 0&  0& 1 & 0\\ 0&  0&  0&0 \end{matrix}\right|$

$\begin{vmatrix} 0&  1&  1&0 \\ 0&  0&  2& 0\\ 0&  0&  0& 3\\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix} 1&  0&  -1/3&0 \\ 0&  1&  -1& 0\\ 0&  0& 1 & 0\\ 0&  0&  0&0 \end{matrix}\right|$

$\begin{vmatrix} 0&  1&  0&0 \\ 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 0&  0&  0& 1\\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix} 1&  -1/2&  1/6&0 \\ 0&  1/2&  -1/2& 0\\ 0&  0& 1/3 & 0\\ 0&  0&  0&0 \end{matrix}\right|$

$\begin{vmatrix} 1&  0&  0&0 \\ 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 0&  0&  0& 0 \end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix} -1/2&  1/6&0&1 \\ 1/2&  -1/2& 0&0\\ 0& 1/3 & 0&0\\ 0&  0&0 &0 \end{matrix}\right|$

The problem is that when I put this matrices on matrixcalc.org I don't become the right solution. Where Is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final step, you can only swap rows, not columns.
So you can get the second, third and fourth rows of S by bringing the row of zeroes to the top.
The first row of S makes no difference to A×S, so choose a row that makes S invertible.

Comment: Do you mean to do like this in the final step?

$\begin{vmatrix}0&  0&  0& 0 \\ 0&  1&  0&0 \\ 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 0&  0&  0& 1\end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix} 0&  0&  0&0\\1&  -1/2&  1/6&0 \\ 0&  1/2&  -1/2& 0\\ 0&  0& 1/3 & 0 \end{matrix}\right|$

I controlled the solution with this matrix and it is correct but I dont understand why.

With this solution shouldn't I get $\begin{vmatrix}0&  0&  0& 0 \\ 0&  1&  0&0 \\ 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 0&  0&  0& 1\end{vmatrix}$?

Comment: Does it work if you left S be the thing with fractions, but put 0,0,0, 1 in the top row

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: The augmented matrix $[M|N]$ is shorthand for MS=N.  Each row operation changes M and N, but the invisible S stays the same.  At the end, the row [0100] multiplied by S gives the second row of S, which must be [1,-1/2,1/6,0].  There is no information about the first row of S, so you are free to make it what you want.  You need S to be in $GL_n$ so put a 1 in the fourth column of the first row.